# How to make openvpn connection available to all hosts on the same subnet?

Tags: networking, openvpn, vpn

For simplicity let's assume the following set up:

2 machines on the same subnet:

Machine-A (mint-17): 192.168.100.2

```
- Has Open-VPN connection which allows it access to private website W1
- Has ip-forwarding enabled
```

Machine-B (mint-18): 192.168.100.3

```
- Has all traffic routed through Machine-A
```

On machine-B, I can browse the web, etc.  However I cannot access website W1.

Not sure what I need to do so that Machine-B would also have access website W1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on machine A:

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Thank you - Iooks like I need to study iptables once I try it out, I'll mark your answer!